# CSS animation only working in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, animation

my css animation only works in google Chrome, any help is appreciated.

In the other browsers, the picture only drop withouth any animation where it should drop with ease, bounce and pivot (so 3 animations)

EDIT: THIS IS MY NEW CODE

```
#divAnimQuille{
    width:330px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#quilleRouge {
    top:-388px;
    position:relative;
    display:block;
}

#quilleRouge.animate {
    display:block;
    position:relative;
    top:0px;

    -webkit-animation: dropQuilleRouge 0.3s ease, bounceQuilleRouge 1s, pivotQuilleRouge 1s 0.1s;
    animation-name: dropQuilleRouge 0.3s ease, bounceQuilleRouge 1s, pivotQuilleRouge 1s 0.1s;

    -webkit-transform-origin: top center;
    transform-origin: top center;
}

/*===============================================================================================*/

@-webkit-keyframes dropQuilleRouge {
    0%{
        top:-388px;
    }
    100%{
        top:0px;
    }
}

/*===============================================================================================*/

@-webkit-keyframes bounceQuilleRouge {
    0%, 20%, 50%, 80%, 100% {-webkit-transform: translateY(0);}
    40% {-webkit-transform: translateY(-30px);}
    60% {-webkit-transform: translateY(-15px);}
}

@keyframes bounceQuilleRouge {
    0%, 20%, 50%, 80%, 100% {transform: translateY(0);}
    40% {transform: translateY(-30px);}
    60% {transform: translateY(-15px);}
}


/*===============================================================================================*/

@-webkit-keyframes pivotQuilleRouge {
    20%, 40%, 60%, 80%, 100% { -webkit-transform-origin: top center; }
    20% { -webkit-transform: rotate(12deg); }   
    40% { -webkit-transform: rotate(-10deg); }
    60% { -webkit-transform: rotate(5deg); }    
    80% { -webkit-transform: rotate(-5deg); }   
    100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); }
}

@keyframes pivotQuilleRouge {
    20%, 40%, 60%, 80%, 100% { -webkit-transform-origin: top center; }
    20% { transform: rotate(12deg); }   
    40% { transform: rotate(-10deg); }
    60% { transform: rotate(5deg); }    
    80% { transform: rotate(-5deg); }   
    100% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
}
```

OLD CODE:

```
#divAnimQuille{
    width:330px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#quilleRouge {
    top:-388px;
    position:relative;
    display:block;
}

#quilleRouge.animate {
    display:block;
    position:relative;
    top:0px;

    -webkit-animation: dropQuilleRouge 0.3s ease;
    -moz-animation-name: dropQuilleRouge 0.3s ease;
    -ms-animation-name: dropQuilleRouge 0.3s ease;
    -o-animation-name: dropQuilleRouge 0.3s ease;
    animation-name: dropQuilleRouge 0.3s ease;

    -webkit-animation:bounceQuilleRouge 1s;
    -moz-animation-name:bounceQuilleRouge 1s;
    -ms-animation-name:bounceQuilleRouge 1s;
    -o-animation-name:bounceQuilleRouge 1s;
    animation-name: bounceQuilleRouge 1s;

    -webkit-animation:pivotQuilleRouge 1s 0.1s; 
    -moz-animation-name:pivotQuilleRouge 1s 0.1s;
    -ms-animation-name:pivotQuilleRouge 1s 0.1s;
    -o-animation-name:pivotQuilleRouge 1s 0.1s;
    animation-name: pivotQuilleRouge 1s 0.1s;

    -webkit-transform-origin: top center;
    -moz-transform-origin: top center;
    -ms-transform-origin: top center;
    o-transform-origin: top center;
}

/*===============================================================================================*/

@-webkit-keyframes dropQuilleRouge {
    0%{
        top:-388px;
    }
    100%{
        top:0px;
    }
}


/*===============================================================================================*/

@-webkit-keyframes bounceQuilleRouge {
    0%, 20%, 50%, 80%, 100% {-webkit-transform: translateY(0);}
    40% {-webkit-transform: translateY(-30px);}
    60% {-webkit-transform: translateY(-15px);}
}

@-moz-keyframes bounceQuilleRouge {
    0%, 20%, 50%, 80%, 100% {-moz-transform: translateY(0);}
    40% {-moz-transform: translateY(-30px);}
    60% {-moz-transform: translateY(-15px);}
}

@-ms-keyframes bounceQuilleRouge {
    0%, 20%, 50%, 80%, 100% {-ms-transform: translateY(0);}
    40% {-ms-transform: translateY(-30px);}
    60% {-ms-transform: translateY(-15px);}
}

@-o-keyframes bounceQuilleRouge {
    0%, 20%, 50%, 80%, 100% {-o-transform: translateY(0);}
    40% {-o-transform: translateY(-30px);}
    60% {-o-transform: translateY(-15px);}
}
@keyframes bounceQuilleRouge {
    0%, 20%, 50%, 80%, 100% {transform: translateY(0);}
    40% {transform: translateY(-30px);}
    60% {transform: translateY(-15px);}
}


/*===============================================================================================*/

@-webkit-keyframes pivotQuilleRouge {
    20%, 40%, 60%, 80%, 100% { -webkit-transform-origin: top center; }
    20% { -webkit-transform: rotate(12deg); }   
    40% { -webkit-transform: rotate(-10deg); }
    60% { -webkit-transform: rotate(5deg); }    
    80% { -webkit-transform: rotate(-5deg); }   
    100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); }
}

@-moz-keyframes pivotQuilleRouge {
    20%, 40%, 60%, 80%, 100% { -webkit-transform-origin: top center; }
    20% { -moz-transform: rotate(12deg); }  
    40% { -moz-transform: rotate(-10deg); }
    60% { -moz-transform: rotate(5deg); }   
    80% { -moz-transform: rotate(-5deg); }  
    100% { -moz-transform: rotate(0deg); }
}

@-ms-keyframes pivotQuilleRouge {
    20%, 40%, 60%, 80%, 100% { -webkit-transform-origin: top center; }
    20% { -ms-transform: rotate(12deg); }   
    40% { -ms-transform: rotate(-10deg); }
    60% { -ms-transform: rotate(5deg); }    
    80% { -ms-transform: rotate(-5deg); }   
    100% { -ms-transform: rotate(0deg); }
}

@-o-keyframes pivotQuilleRouge {
    20%, 40%, 60%, 80%, 100% { -webkit-transform-origin: top center; }
    20% { -o-transform: rotate(12deg); }    
    40% { -o-transform: rotate(-10deg); }
    60% { -o-transform: rotate(5deg); } 
    80% { -o-transform: rotate(-5deg); }    
    100% { -o-transform: rotate(0deg); }
}

@keyframes pivotQuilleRouge {
    20%, 40%, 60%, 80%, 100% { -webkit-transform-origin: top center; }
    20% { transform: rotate(12deg); }   
    40% { transform: rotate(-10deg); }
    60% { transform: rotate(5deg); }    
    80% { transform: rotate(-5deg); }   
    100% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
}
```

The code is triggered on a certain scroll position:

```
$(window).scroll(function (event) {

var hauteurHeader = $('#header').height();

var y = $(this).scrollTop();

if (y >= hauteurHeader - 100) {
    $('#quilleRouge').addClass('animate');
}
```

});

Comment: `@-webkit-keyframes dropQuilleRouge` will only be applied to webkit browsers, you are trying to use it on all.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to specify the keyframes function for all browsers - not only for webkit:

```
@-webkit-keyframes dropQuilleRouge {
    0%{
        top:-388px;
    }
    100%{
        top:0px;
    }
}
@-moz-keyframes dropQuilleRouge {
    0%{
        top:-388px;
    }
    100%{
        top:0px;
    }
}
@-o-keyframes dropQuilleRouge {
    0%{
        top:-388px;
    }
    100%{
        top:0px;
    }
}
@keyframes dropQuilleRouge {
    0%{
        top:-388px;
    }
    100%{
        top:0px;
    }
}
```

Also - correct me on this if it changed, but as far as I know there is no @-ms-keyframes for IE, since older IE browser don't support keyframe animations, while IE10+ use standard css3 syntax.

Comment: This didn't fix it, the drop does work but there should be an ease for it.  Now it only goes to 100 % without any animation and the 2 other animations don't work also.

Comment: You don't need @-moz-keyframes and @-o-keyframes. IE10+, FF and Opera support @keyframes while Chrome and Safari support webkit. IE9 and under doesn't support it at all. See here [W3School](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_animation-keyframes.asp)

Comment: @MathieuDésilets Remove '-name:' from '*-animation-name' where you call it in class - you have a typo - to call the animation as shorthand use just 'animation' - not 'animation-name'.

Comment: @snaplemouton Older versions of those browsers don't support standard syntax so you still need it. Also a few mobile browsers also won't work without it.

Comment: @easwee don't know who to believe, I updated the code in the OP

Comment: @Mathieu Désilets, easwee is right. Mozilla 5.0 require -moz and opera 12.0 require -o. Man... how much I wish they'd just get rid of all the older browsers and force people to get the newer browsers...

Comment: @snaplemouton  Ok I got it working in Chrome and Firefox, Opera's timing is off but I can live with it, IE still not working though

Comment: @Mathieu Désilets, if you are using IE9 and under it isn't supported. Only IE10+ support keyframes animation.

Comment: @snaplemouton That is true.

Comment: @snaplemouton  Ok I can live with this, last issue, the animation has 3 parts, the last part (pivot) starts after a delay now, it used to be fine but now it's always this way, any idea as to why ? I added a second animation can CSS be overloaded ?

Comment: @MathieuDésilets - You need to match your times. First `animation-duration` is `0.3s`; second is `1s` - you can use `animation-delay` to delay the second animation by `0.3s` so it will start when the first one is over and so on.

Comment: @easwee thanks it's fine now, anyway to prevent the animation for IE 9 and older ?

Comment: @MathieuDésilets Place the reset rules in a conditional comment `<!--[if lte IE 9]><style type="text/css"> .ieNoAnimationCssHere{} </style><![endif]-->`